# Correct way to use third-party libraries in cmake project

Tags: cmake, libraries

I'm working on project that use some third-party libraries. I can clone and put them into my project as a `git submodule` and use `add_subdirectory` to use them in my project. But it take much time to compile these libs, and I can not manage `cmake` variables in my projects, and `install()` command make my package contains many things that I don't need.

So what is correct way to use third-party libraries in my project. I can not tell the client to install these libraries as dependencies of my project.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Answering this question requires to cover few aspects, you will find below two sections:

- config-file package
- ExternalProject CMake module

### config-file package

If you are looking into integrating libraries that are not built within the scope of your project, the first step is to make sure the libraries all provide a config-file package.

A config-file package usually include files like `FooConfig.cmake`, `FooConfigVersion.cmake` and `FooTargets.cmake`.

Generally speaking, if the library `Foo` is already using CMake and already provide a config-file package, configuring your project with `-DFoo_DIR:PATH=/path/to/build-or-install-dir/` allow you to call `find_package(Foo REQUIRED)` from your own project. This will import CMake targets that you can link against your own libraries or executables.

Now if the library `Foo`is  not already using CMake, there are options:

- Case 1:

  - (a) library `Foo` is already using CMake
  - (b) but do **NOT** provide a config-file package
  - **action**: I suggest to improve their build system
- Case 2:

  - (1) library `Foo` is **not** using CMake
  - (2) and maintainer of `Foo` are willing to transition to CMake (or at least have the `CMakeLists.txt` along side their current build system)
  - **action**: I suggest to improve their build system
- Case 3:

  - (1) library `Foo` is **not** using CMake
  - (2) and maintainer of `Foo` do not want to transition to CMake
  - (3) but maintainer are willing to generate config-file package from their current build system
  - **action**: I suggest to help them. This is for example what was done for Qt5, it now provides a config-file package.
- Case 4:

  - (1) library  `Foo` is **not** using CMake
  - (2) and maintainer of `Foo` do not want (or are not ready) to transition to CMake.
  - (3) and the current build system is not working well, or the library is difficult to build with a wider range of compiler, or does not support cross-compilation
  - **action**: create a project (ideally on GitHub) named `foo-cmake-buildsystem` that will allow to build the library by either

    - configuring the project with the path to an existing source tree
    - having the project downloading the source for you
    - this is for example done for CPython. There is a project named `python-cmake-buildsystem` available on GitHub
- Case 5:

  - (1) for any reason the maintainer of `Foo` do not want to transition, or maintaining an alternative build system is not possible, or library is already available on the system
  - **action**: You could create a `FindFoo.cmake` that would create imported targets.

    - such file could be specific to your project or could be contributed to CMake directly
    - this is for example the case of `FindOpenSSL.cmake`, `FindGit.cmake`, ...

To learn more about config-file package, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html

### ExternalProject CMake module

If the library `Foo` is:

- (1) not available on the system:

  - or can't be installed using package manager
  - or working with the community maintaining packages (debian, conda-forge, chocolatey, ...) to have such package is not possible
- (2) or need to be compiled specially for your project

Then, the `ExternalProject` CMake module will allow you to download, configure, build ... these projects from within your own project.

There are few approaches to make this happen.

Here is one that has been working well: You could setup a 2-level build system that we call: `SuperBuild`.

To support the `SuperBuild` approach, your CMakeLists.txt could have the following structure:

```
project(AwesomeProject)

[...]

option(Awesome_ENABLE_EXTRA "Enable more awesome stuff" OFF)

option(AwesomeProject_SUPERBUILD "Build ${PROJECT_NAME} and the projects it depends on." ON)

[...]

if(AwesomeProject_SUPERBUILD)
  include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SuperBuild.cmake")
  return()
endif()

find_package(Foo REQUIRED)

add_library(AwesomeLib ....)
target_link_libraries(AwesomeLib PUBLIC Foo)

[...]
```

Then, in the file `SuperBuild.cmake` you would roughly have these two calls:

```
ExternalProject_Add(Foo
  GIT_REPOSITORY "git://github.com/Foo/Foo"
  GIT_TAG "123456"
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Foo
  BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Foo-build
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
    -DFOO_ENABLE_BAR:BOOL=1
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  )


ExternalProject_Add(AwesomeProject
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/AwesomeProject-build
  DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
    -Foo_DIR:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Foo-build
    -DAwesome_ENABLE_EXTRA:BOOL=${Awesome_ENABLE_EXTRA}
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  )
```

This means that you usual build tree will now be found in the subdirectory `AwesomeProject-build`.

Note that `Foo-build` and `AwesomeProject-build` are two independent build tree, the link between them
is the config-file package discussed above.

This is made possible by configuring `AwesomeProject` sub project with `-Foo_DIR:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Foo-build`
and the calling `find_package(Foo REQUIRED)`.

If you use tools like VisualStudio you can open the solution file found in any of these sub-directory.

To learn more about external  project: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html

### conclusion

There are many more details, but I hope this will allow you to get a better understanding of what is possible.

Comment: "I suggest to improve their build system" is entirely unhelpful and provides no information whatsoever as to how to remedy the situation... How is this a top search result??

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the suggestion to improve the build-system relates to the lack of config-file package. The suggested action is to provide such file. This guide will be helpful: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html