# Building mongo-driver-cxx on Windows

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm trying to download externally the mongo-cxx-driver on Windows from the given github repositories, but unfortunately my knowledge of cmake is less to none. I found the next given script in one of the stackoverflow questions: [Building mongo-cxx-driver using CMake ExternalProject_Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717207/building-mongo-cxx-driver-using-cmake-externalproject-add), but even when it seems to work, it doesn't work. It does make the given project but without the libraries. May someone help with creating those libraries through cmake, externally or internally after downloading the mongo-c-driver and the mongo-cxx-driver from the github repositories.
If someone could go through the needed steps I'd be delighted.
Also if boost could be removed from this equation, it would be good.

The CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) 

project(Test)

option(${PROJECT_NAME}_SUPERBUILD "Build ${PROJECT_NAME} and the projects it depends on." ON)

if(${PROJECT_NAME}_SUPERBUILD)

    include(ExternalProject)

    set(common_cmake_cache_args
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
    )
    if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
        list(APPEND common_cmake_cache_args
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        )
    endif()

    ExternalProject_Add(libmongoc
        GIT_REPOSITORY  "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git"
        GIT_TAG         "1.16.2"
        GIT_PROGRESS    1
        GIT_SHALLOW     1
        SOURCE_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc"
        BINARY_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-build"
        INSTALL_DIR     "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install"
        CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
            ${common_cmake_cache_args}
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install
            -DENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_STATIC:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_EXTRA_ALIGNMENT:BOOL=OFF
        #INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )
    set(libmongoc-1.0_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install/lib/cmake/libmongoc-1.0/")
    set(libbson-1.0_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongoc-install/lib/cmake/libbson-1.0/")

    ExternalProject_Add(libmongocxx
        GIT_REPOSITORY  "https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git"
        GIT_TAG         "r3.4.2"
        GIT_PROGRESS    1
        GIT_SHALLOW     1
        SOURCE_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx"
        BINARY_DIR      "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx-build"
        INSTALL_DIR     "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx-install"
        CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
            ${common_cmake_cache_args}
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx-install
            -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
            -DENABLE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
            -DENABLE_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
            -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST:BOOL=OFF
            -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_MNMLSTC:BOOL=ON
            -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_STD:BOOL=OFF
            -Dlibmongoc-1.0_DIR:PATH=${libmongoc-1.0_DIR}
            -Dlibbson-1.0_DIR:PATH=${libbson-1.0_DIR}
        DEPENDS
            libmongoc
    )
    set(libmongocxx_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx-install/lib/cmake/libmongocxx-3.4.2/")
    set(libbsoncxx_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmongocxx-install//lib/cmake/libbsoncxx-3.4.2/")


    function(ExternalProject_AlwaysConfigure proj)
      # This custom external project step forces the configure and later
      # steps to run.
      _ep_get_step_stampfile(${proj} "configure" stampfile)
      ExternalProject_Add_Step(${proj} forceconfigure
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove ${stampfile}
        COMMENT "Forcing configure step for '${proj}'"
        DEPENDEES build
        ALWAYS 1
        )
    endfunction()

    ExternalProject_Add(${PROJECT_NAME}
        SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}"
        BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-build"
        DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
            ${common_cmake_cache_args}
            -D${PROJECT_NAME}_SUPERBUILD:BOOL=OFF
            -Dlibbsoncxx_DIR:PATH=${libbsoncxx_DIR}
            -Dlibmongocxx_DIR:PATH=${libmongocxx_DIR}
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        DEPENDS
            libmongocxx
    )
    ExternalProject_AlwaysConfigure(${PROJECT_NAME})
    return()
endif()

message(STATUS "Configuring inner-build")

find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)

add_executable(test_mongocxx test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_mongocxx PUBLIC ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(test_mongocxx PUBLIC ${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(test_mongocxx PUBLIC ${LIBMONGOCXX_DEFINITIONS})
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? I've always installed mongo-c and mongocxx drivers directly running the commands and using MVStudio MSBuild.exe, so probably not what you want I guess.

Comment: Can you please go with me through the steps of setting it up?

Comment: Best is to follow the installation guide: 1) Install mongo-c-driver http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html 2) Install mongocxx: http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/
You need to share what have you done and what error are you getting so we can help you.

Comment: Can you just go with me through the steps of installing it?