# How to generate a DLL linked to a static library with CMake

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

The main objective with this question is to write an `CMakeLists.txt` to generate a dynamic library, "containing/linked" a static library.

Let me create the scenario:

- My C++ code is written in `mycode.cpp`
- In `mycode.cpp`, I call some functions from `libthirdparty.a` (static library)
- I want to generate `libmylib.so` (shared library) to be dynamically linked by others
- `libmylib.so` must to "contain" `libthirdparty.a`

My attempt to write this script is at the lines bellow:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -m64 -fPIC ")
add_executable(myapp mycode.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp thirdparty)
add_library(mylib SHARED myapp)
```

But of course this is not working and I would like some help to write it correctly.

Comment: Try target_link_libraries(mylib thirdparty)

Comment: where? before, after or in place of any other command?

Comment: After you do a add_library(mylib SHARED mycode.cpp)  just add the line I previously suggested. The target needs to exist before you can specify its properties.

Answer (score 1):

For now, let's remove the `myapp` and focus only on the library you are trying to create.

That said, here is what you could do

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(AwesomeLib)

include(GenerateExportHeader)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

find_package(ThirdParty REQUIRED)

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ThirdParty)

# Note: If you library will be cross-platform, flag should be conditionally specified. Have a look at generator-expression
target_compile_options(mylib PRIVATE -Wall -Werror)

generate_export_header(mylib)

# TODO:
# * add install rules
# * generate config-file package
# * add tests
```

Notes:

- `generate_export_header` will generate "mylib_export.h" header with the MYLIB_EXPORT macro for exporting symbols. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html
- to understand the idea behind `find_package(ThirdParty REQUIRED)`, I recommend you read config-file package. See [Correct way to use third-party libraries in cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564251/correct-way-to-use-third-party-libraries-in-cmake-project/51567322#51567322)
- to learn more about generator expression. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html